# Is there any way to cache loaded images on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I load an image (.tar) into local docker repository and then Kubernetes pulls that Image into a container. After the application is up and running I want to remove that image from local docker repository, is that right way or Kubernetes still needs that image inside docker local repository?
I have tested when deleting that image, my Application still works, but if I want to scale up or scale down, I got a problem because the image is missing.

I presume, if the Pod goes down, Kubernetes will seek for Image again in docker repository?

Is there any way to cache that Image inside Kubernetes, so no need to pull again from docker repository?

The reason why I want to delete these images right after Application run on Kubernetes is security, I don't want to leave my images inside docker repository so a user can't extract that image and export it somewhere...

Comment: ...that's what the repository is for.  If you don't want your images to be publicly available then you need to secure it as well as the rest of your Kubernetes installation.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for response, ok so holding images inside local repository is mandatory? there is no chance to have working solution without repo all the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I presume, if the Pod goes down, Kubernetes will seek for Image again in docker repository?

Yes.

> Is there any way to cache that Image inside Kubernetes, so no need to pull again from docker repository?

When you pull an image it's cached locally by docker or your runtime manager.

> The reason why I want to delete these images right after Application run on Kubernetes is security, I don't want to leave my images inside docker repository so a user can't extract that image and export it somewhere...

If you are concerned about security you shouldn't put sensitive information in the image (passwords, credentials, keys). That's why there are [Kubernetes Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) or tools like [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/).

If you are concerned about keeping intellectual property private you should consider using a private container image repository or private [Docker registry](https://github.com/docker/distribution)